# core php session is lost in codeigniter when redirecting controller to controller

Tags: codeigniter

core php session is lost in codeigniter when redirecting from one controller to another.
In the first controller, it works perfectly when we assign value to it. Also, in the first controller, the session is correctly handled but after a redirect to another controller, the session is lost.

**Here is first controller:**

```
$_session['user'] = $data[0]['u_name']; // assign value to session 
echo $_session['user']  // works fine here and print user name
redirect("useraccount",'refresh'); // redirection to user account
```

its not working in useraccount.php controller

**here second controller**

```
public function index() {

    if(isset($_session['user']))
      echo $_session['user'];
    else 
      echo "no session";
    //$data['main'] = 'users/dashboard';
    //$this->load->view('index',$data);

}
```

it is printing no session. How do I pass the session to 2nd controller after redirecting
 to second controller?

note: i want to use core php session and not codeigniter session.

Answer (score 2):

Is there something wrong with:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user', $data[0]['u_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP variable names are case sensitive. it should be

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            ^^^^^^^--- note: all CAPS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `session_start()` property to access core php session

Try this

```
public function index()    
{
   session_start();
   if(isset($_session['user']))
   echo $_session['user'];
   else 
    echo "no session";
   //$data['main'] = 'users/dashboard';
   //$this->load->view('index',$data);

}
```